# Simple Ticker (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, slide, ticker

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to show only one `li` at a time using slide effect, thats it. I'd like to avoid using plugins for something as simple as this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think he is using rent-a-coder, and is getting paid for this ;)

Comment: SO isn't the same anymore I guess. I've asked a lot of similar questions and always received help, but maybe those guys have left and you have arrived? Thanks anyway, I figured out a solution myself.

Comment: is my solution not what you are looking for? If its not please comment my answer so i can adapt the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have made something simple up for you (based on your description), just to point you in the right direction:

check it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/ACenH/234/

```
function slider(container, delay){
$container = $(container) // select the container elements and store them in a variable

if ( !$container.length ){ return fasle; } // checks if the slider exists in your dom. if not the function ends here...

    var slides = $container.length, // gives back the total LI's you have
        slide = 0 // set the actual li to show

        setInterval(function(){ // set a Interval for your main function
            if (slide == slides - 1) { // if the actual slide is equal the total slides (-1 because eq is 0 based and length gives back the number of elements in the jQuery object) the slide counter is set to 0
               $container.slideDown(); // and all slides a shown again
               slide = 0;
            } else {
              $container.eq(slide).slideUp(); //slides the selected slide up i think you could think of a solution with .next() instead of eq() 
              slide++; // slide counter +1
            }

        }, delay)

}

slider('ul > li', 2000); // call your slider function
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question already mentions jquery as the javascript framework of choice. The best place you can start is the jquery docs on hiding:

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

and sliding:

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/
http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/
http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/